# How HAML can recognize the end of the block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, haml

```
= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => "create"}) do |f|
    = render :partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}
    #form_buttons= submit_tag "Create Subject"
```

Noticed that form_for has a "do",so it needs a "end", but how does HAML knows where to end the "end" ?

Sorry about my English,hope you can understand what am I  talking about!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HAML uses indentation to delimit blocks in the same way the Python language does. Perhaps you should read  a basic [tutorial](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html) or [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml#Principles) for more information.

```
= form_for(:subject, :url => {:action => "create"}) do |f|
    = render :partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}
    #you can use f here
# you can't use f here
```

Comment: Never learned Python before but I think it is a fabulous way to write HAML instead of using ERB.

Comment: and it's great that HAML has the indenting feature like Python

Comment: I updated my answer. You probably mean how to write HTML instead of using ERB. :)

Comment: I found it,just like you said

Comment: Ruby blocks, like XHTML tags, don’t need to be explicitly closed in Haml. Rather, they’re automatically closed, based on indentation.

Answer (score 2):

HAML uses indentation for block structure.
More simply put, when the code actually 'outdents' it's an implied end (either to the html tag OR the ruby do-end block).
So what in html/ruby would be

```
...
loop1
  loop2
    code_for_loop2
  end # of loop2
end # of loop1
...

in haml becomes
...
loop1
  loop2
    code for loop2
...
```

p.s. indent by 2 also, spaces not tabs.