# getting SyntaxError in PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am getting the following error

```
C:/ruby/rails/forum/app/views/posts/index.html.haml:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end ...:Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer.... ... ^ C:/ruby/rails/forum/app/views/posts/index.html.haml:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

my `index.html.haml` file looks like this:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
%h2=@post.title
%p
 Published at
=time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```

Comment: please format haml as it is in your file

Comment: Lines 7 and 10 of the snippet provided are definitely not responsible for the exception raised.

Comment: yes i did but its not working

Comment: You're sure this is the entirety of your `... /views/posts/index.html.haml` file? Because the error message is indicating lines 7 and 10, but according to your question, there are only 5 lines in your Haml file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use post.title instead of @post.title i.e,

```
- @posts.each do |post|
%h2=post.title
%p
Published at
=time_ago_in_words(post.created_at
```

Comment: Exactly. Post is not the instance variable from index, but this is local variable inside the code block.

Comment: i tried post.title too... the problem is with the first line i think

Comment: The error message says expecting keyword_end. HAML uses indentation for block structure. I think you must indent your code a bit. There is a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770546/how-haml-can-recognize-the-end-of-the-block#5783369) for using the block in haml. I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Vikram is right that you should be using post instead of @post, however this particular error is being caused by incorrect indentation. HAML does not use closing tags, so it's completely dependent on indentation to determine which elements are parents, children, etc.

Should look like this:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  %h2= post.title
  %p
    Published at
    = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```